# Angular PrimeNG megamenu visible false doesn't work

Tags: angular, primeng, megamenu

Angular PrimeNG megamenu visible false doesn't work.

```
<p-megaMenu [model]="menuItems"></p-megaMenu>

this.menuItems = [
              {
                  label: 'Home', items: null, routerLink: ['']
              },
              {
                  label: 'About', visible: false,
                  items[{label: 'About 1.1', visible: false},{label: 'About 1.2'}]
              }]
```

In above example I have used visible false twice with About and About 1.1, but not of it work. Does anyone has any idea on how to make it working?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma here after false in your example items[{label: 'About 1.1', visible: false,}  Can't see any problems otherwise.

Comment: It was just a formatting mistake. It doesn't work even after that.

Answer (score 0):

From [MegaMenu doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/megamenu) :

> MegaMenu uses the common menumodel api to define its items, visit MenuModel API for details.

So you should be able to use `visible` property to hide a menu item.

But if you have a look at [megamenu.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/megamenu/megamenu.ts) source code, you'll see that nothing references this property whereas it's the case with [menubar.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/menubar/menubar.ts) source code for instance :

```
[ngClass]="{'ui-helper-hidden': child.visible === false}"
```

To work around this problem, why wouldn't you remove items which have `visible` property false from `menuItems` array ?

Comment: That is a workaround option to remove elements from array dynamically.  I was looking for a direct answer to check if they have included it with some other version/release.

Comment: You can directly ask PrimeNG team on their forum or Github.